# retrieve cell string values in a column between two unknown indexes based on substrings location

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, substring

I need to locate the first location where the word 'then' appears on Words table. I'm trying to get a code to consolidate all strings on 'text' column from this location till the first text with a substring '666' or '999' in it (in this case a combination of their, stoma22, fe156, sligh334, pain666 (the desired subtrings_output = 'theirfe156sligh334pain666').
I've tried:

```
their_loc = np.where(words['text'].str.contains(r'their', na =True))[0][0]
666_999_loc = np.where(words['text'].str.contains(r'666', na =True))[0][0]
subtrings_output = Words['text'].loc[Words.index[their_loc:666_999_loc]]
```

as you can see I'm not sure how to extend the conditioning of 666_999_loc to include substring 666 or 999, also slicing the indexing between two variables renders an error. Many thanks

Words table:

| page no | text | font |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | they | 0 |
| 1 | ate | 0 |
| 1 | apples | 0 |
| 2 | and | 0 |
| 2 | then | 1 |
| 2 | their | 0 |
| 2 | stoma22 | 0 |
| 2 | fe156 | 1 |
| 2 | sligh334 | 0 |
| 2 | pain666 | 1 |
| 2 | given | 0 |
| 2 | the | 1 |
| 3 | fruit | 0 |

Comment: To extend the conditioning, just find two separate locations, one for substring 666, one for 999. Then check if both location exists. If not, store the one that exists in a final_loc variable. If both locations exist, compare the two and set final_loc to be the earlier one.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add one for the end of the slice, and add an `or` condition to the `np.where` of the `666_or_999_loc` using the `|` operator.

```py
text_col = words['text']

their_loc = np.where(text_col.str.contains(r'their', na=True))[0][0]

contains_666_or_999_loc = np.where(text_col.str.contains('666', na=True) |
                                   text_col.str.contains('999', na=True))[0][0]

subtrings_output = ''.join(text_col.loc[words.index[their_loc:contains_666_or_999_loc + 1]])

print(subtrings_output)
```

---

Output:

```
theirstoma22fe156sligh334pain666
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, use [`pandas.Series.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) with `"".join()`.

> `Series.idxmax(axis=0, skipna=True, *args, **kwargs)`
> **Return the row label of the maximum value**.
> If multiple values equal the maximum, the first row label with that
> value is returned.

So, assuming (`Words`) is your dataframe, try this :

```
their_loc = Words["text"].str.contains("their").idxmax()

_666_999_loc = Words["text"].str.contains("666").idxmax()

subtrings_output = "".join(Words["text"].loc[Words.index[their_loc:_666_999_loc+1]])
```

Output :

```
print(subtrings_output)
#theirstoma22fe156sligh334pain666

#their stoma22 fe156 sligh334 pain666 # <- with " ".join()
```